# Overriding Joomla 3.x core controller

Tags: php, joomla

First and foremost, please acknowledge that upgrading to Joomla 4 or 5 is not an option for my situation. I need this to be done in Joomla 3.10.10.

I want to override the core Joomla UsersController located in components\com_users\controller.php. I need to change the code it contains.
There seems to be no documentation on the matter.

The only [plausible solution](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=991507) I found, namely creating a code folder in the template I'm using, does not work.

Is there a way to override a controller's code without risk of it being overwritten by a Joomla update ?

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 real straightforward methods:

- Modify the core and then ensure that this modification is preserved when updating the website.
- Create a plugin that is triggered when a onUserAfterSave event is triggered that does what you want

In my opinion, the second option should work in most scenarios (the first option will always work, but it's a core modification) - in fact, I can't think of a scenario where it doesn't work (even, for example, if you don't want the user to be created based on a specific rule, you can have it created by the core controller and then deleting it/updating it in the plugin).